# Proof on unitary diagonalisable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, diagonalization

My task is the following:

$Let\,\, A,U \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \,\,and\,\,assume \,\,that \,\, U \,\,is \,\,unitary \,\, and \,\, that \,\,U^*AU \,\,is\,\, a\,\, diagonal\,\, matrix.\\Show \,\, that \,\,A \,\,is\,\,normal. $

My approach was:

$M:= U^*AU \Rightarrow A = UMU^*. Now \,\, I \,\, want \,\, to \,\, show \,\, that \,\, A \,\, is \,\, normal \,\,so\,\,I \,\, have \,\, to \,\, show:\\A^*A=AA^*$

But when I now insert $UMU^*$ for A I don't get far. I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your notation:
\begin{eqnarray}
A=UMU^*\Rightarrow A^*&=&UM^*U^*,\\
AA^*=UMU^*UM^*U^*&=&UMM^*U^*,\\
A^*A=UM^*U^*UMU^*&=&UM^*MU^*.
\end{eqnarray}
Then $A$ is normal, as diagonal matrices $M$ and $M^*$ commute.

Comment: Why is A* = U M* U* shouldn't it be A* = U* M* U

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are matrices, then $(XY)^*=Y^*X^*$.

Comment: $A^*=(UMU^*)^*=(U^*)^*M^*U^*=UM^*U^*$.

Comment: Ok so my thought was $A = UMU^* \,\, then \,\, A* = (UMU^*)^* = U^* M^* U^{**} = U^* M^* U$

Comment: But I looked it up, seems like I got something wrong. Thank you